# Python: subprocess call, imagemagick. 'non-conforming drawing primitive'

Tags: python, string, imagemagick

I've written a script that takes in data from a csv file and stores it. I then use ImageMagick's convert/draw command in order to write text with the variables onto the images.

It's having issues printing out onto the image. For example, THIS works correctly and writes 'hello' onto the image.

```
#this works
test = 'hello'
subprocess.call('convert rgb10.png -pointsize 50 -draw "text 180,180 %s " rgb10-n.png' % (test,), shell=True)
```

But when I try to pass a number, even if it's technically a string, it doesn't display it onto the image. **The subprocess call is the same**

```
#this does NOT work, subprocess call is the same
test = '9'
subprocess.call('convert rgb10.png -pointsize 50 -draw "text 180,180 %s " rgb10-n.png' % (test,), shell=True)
```

^Above does NOT work and gives the following error: 
**convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `text' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3192.**

EDIT: *Does convert -draw not support integers/numbers?*

Comment: The text needs to be in single quotes inside the double quotes... `-draw "text 180,180 'Some funky text'"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I thought that but then how come the first one works WITHOUT the single quotes?

Comment: @MarkSetchell also, tried it with the single quotes and it doesn't work.